# How to avoid MySQL replication corruption while executing flush-logs command

Tags: linux, mysql, mysql-replication

I have three servers running MySQL, let's say A, B and C. Server A is the master, and server B is the slave. I want to do mysql replication between server A and B, at the same time, I also want to use my backup solution to backup mysql data from server A to server C. However, my backup solution needs to run "flush-logs" command to create new mysql binary log. So I'm afraid changing mysql binary logs will affect mysql replication process. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What is your backup solution here?

Comment: My backup solution is using flush-logs to create a new binary log, then transfer the previous binlog to destination and restore.

Comment: Did you answer yourself how `flush logs` is gonna affect mysql replication process?

Comment: No, I just want to know whether flush-logs can affect replication or not. If it truly affects, then what is the solution.

Comment: I've never heard `flush logs` will somehow corrupt a slave.

Answer (score 0):

Flush Logs is safe to do while replication is on, it only switches the current log file.
The switching of log files is also done according to the max_binlog_size variable's value.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always the case. I've learned it the hard way.